# Android: receiving MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sd-card

I have an application that scans the sd-card and make a list of video files stored in it. Then there is an option of playing the video files. All I want to know is

1- How can I register various actions or notifications like Action.Media.Unmount, Action.Media.Bad.Removal etc in my Manifest file
2- How can I use the braodcast receiver in my code.. I have tried couple of codes but they didn't work. If someone can give me of an example here, I shall be greatly thankful..

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should read the documentation. It's a fairly simple method to register a BroadcastReceiver for those Intents.
Just read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver).

If, after reading you still have some kind of problem, just say what error are you getting and the code/xml you're using.